# Aggregating using function diff with non-sequential rows

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions, diff

I am rather new to r and I am self teaching myself how to use it so hopefully I can explain my question well.

In my data there are 4 columns:

```
1. Code=Location of a plot
2. Event= Pre or Post. Refers to whether the year of sampling was before or after a disturbance
3. Season= The season the sampling was done in
4. Total= Number of individuals found in plot
```

I would like to aggregate the data so that I have one row for each location and season which contains the change total between pre and post fire.

I would like the change to always be calculated Pre - Post and in my data it is not always in that order.

What I have:

```
Code   Event Season Total
A      Post  AUTUMN     2
A      Pre   AUTUMN     5
A      Pre   SUMMER    15
A      Post  SUMMER    40
B      Pre   AUTUMN     5
B      Post  AUTUMN     8
```

What I would like to have:

```
Code   Season   Change
A      AUTUMN        3
A      SUMMER      -25
B      AUTUMN       -3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `diff` on the 'Total' after grouping by 'Code' and 'Season'

```
aggregate(cbind(Change = Total) ~ Code + Season, df1, diff)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Code, Season) %>%
   summarise(Change = Total[Event == "Pre"] - Total[Event == "Post"])
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Code [2]
#  Code  Season Change
#  <chr> <chr>   <int>
#1 A     AUTUMN      3
#2 A     SUMMER    -25
#3 B     AUTUMN     -3
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Change = Total[Event == 'Pre'] - Total[Event == 'Post']), .(Code, Season)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Code = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Event = c("Post", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post"), Season = c("AUTUMN", "AUTUMN", 
"SUMMER", "SUMMER", "AUTUMN", "AUTUMN"), Total = c(2L, 5L, 15L, 
40L, 5L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
dfout <- aggregate(Change~Code + Season,
                   transform(df,Change = Total*ifelse(Event=="Post",-1,1)),
                   sum)
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  Code Season Change
1    A AUTUMN      3
2    B AUTUMN     -3
3    A SUMMER    -25
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Code = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Event = c("Post", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post"), Season = c("AUTUMN", "AUTUMN", 
"SUMMER", "SUMMER", "AUTUMN", "AUTUMN"), Total = c(2L, 5L, 15L, 
40L, 5L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```